# Recurrence Relation and Divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, divisibility, recreational-mathematics

I've been trying an old question from Gardiner's excellent Mathematical Olympiad Handbook which drove me mad a few years ago and continues to do so now!

Consider the recurrence relation

$$u_n = (n-1)u_{n-1} + 1 \, , \quad u_1 = 1$$

When is $u_n$ divisible by $n$?

It's not hard to show that

$$u_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(n-1)!}{k!} $$

which is exactly sequence [A000522](https://oeis.org/A000522). However this observation doesn't seem to help a huge amount.

The first few $n$ for which the criterion are satisfied are

$$n=1,2,4,5,10,13,16$$

which doesn't lend itself to an obvious conjecture!

Does anyone have an inkling as to how to attack this problem? Hints very welcome!

Comment: I get $u_{16} \equiv 12 \pmod{16}$, and the first few $n$ to be $$1,2,4,5,10,13,20,26,37,52,65,74,130,148,185,260,370,463,\\481,740,926,962,1852,1924,2315,2405,4630,4810,6019,9260$$ which leads to [this sequence](https://oeis.org/A064383).

Comment: Apologies - you are right, my $16$ was erroneous. Looks like there's no closed form for that sequence, so this is quite a mean problem for high school kids!

Comment: Could be just a mistake. Are there newer editions or errata one could check?

Comment: Of course, the OEIS page does suggest an interesting relationship to $e$, though this seems unlikely to have been Gardiner's motivation, seeing as the paper was published some $10$ years after his book!

Comment: I've checked the newest edition and seems to still be in. Can't find any errata sadly.

Comment: The obvious erratum would be to check when the sequence is divisible by $n-1$, which gives the answer $n=2$ only. This seems to me to be too trivial, but perhaps isn't for the intended audience! The erroneous problem is nonetheless interesting though.

Comment: One could consider asking Gardiner, if there's an accessible email address.

Comment: The amazon page for this book lists a.d.gardiner (at) bham.ac.uk  .